# SDTT warning: "The property priceSpecification is not recognized by Google for an object of type Product."

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have the following JSON-LD and am trying to represent a pay monthly product such as a mobile phone contract which consists of an upfront fee and a monthly fee.

When I try to add the `unitCode`, I get the following warning:

> The property `priceSpecification` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Product`.

```json
{ 
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Apple iPhone",
  "image": [
   "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
   "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
 ],
"description": "Apple iPhone XS ...",
 "sku": "0446310786",
 "mpn": "925872",
 "brand": {
  "@type": "Thing",
  "name": "ACME"
   },
  "review": {
   "@type": "Review",
  "reviewRating": {
  "@type": "Rating",
  "ratingValue": "4",
  "bestRating": "5"
  },
"author": {
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Fred Benson"
}
},
"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": "4.4",
"reviewCount": "89"
 },
 "offers": {
"@type": "Offer",
"url": "https://example.com/anvil",
"priceCurrency": "GBP",
"price": "39.99",
"priceValidUntil": "2020-11-05",
"itemCondition": "https://schema.org/UsedCondition",
"availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
"seller": {
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "Executive Objects"
}
},
"priceSpecification": {
    "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
    "price": "25",
    "priceCurrency": "GBP",
    "referenceQuantity": {
      "unitCode": "MON"
    }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `priceSpecification` property to the `Offer`, not to the `Product`.

```json
{ 
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",

  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",

    "priceSpecification": {
      "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification"
    }

  }

}
```

You can find the expected domain/range of a property on its page. For [`priceSpecification`](https://schema.org/priceSpecification), it says:

> **Used on these types**
>   `Demand`
>   `Offer`
>   `TradeAction`

So, it’s not expected on `Product`.